# Finding Similarity between objects' attributes for classification possibly using OWL

Tags: c#, semantics, owl

My problem is complicated semantically speaking. Suppose I have objects with the following attributes :

```
Obj1 attribute-A attribute-B attribute-C
Obj2 attribute-M1 attribute-M2 attribute-M3
Obj3 attribute-X attribute-Y attribute-Z
```

Obj1.attribute-A and Obj3.attribute-Z are exactly the same but because they are written by different programmers their namings are different. Same applies to Obj2.attribute-M1 and Obj3.attribute-Y and so on.

How can I capture such similarity in C# ? I was thinking about describing all these attributes using OWL. So the first part of question is : providing metadata about each object using owl is the best solution ?

Second part of my question : I spent long time reviewing semantic libraries which provide RDF/RDFS/OWL support in .NET Framework but I couldn't find realistic solutions among best hits I found DotNetRdf but they don't provide any support for OWL as well as its very static in terms working with light semantics. Do you recommend any good solution for my problem ?